# what statistical test to use in this context please?

Tags: model-selection, importance

I am a newcomer to statistics and am struggling to work out what statistical test would be appropriate to use in the following scenario: determine whether 'hours of sleep' is a better predictor than 'having breakfast' in determining likelihood of 'falling asleep at work' ?

Comment: what's a type of your variable 'falling asleep at work' ? binary 1 & 0?

Comment: yes it is 1 and 0

Comment: You can use for your goal logistic regression but your variables must be the same scale. I mean 'having breakfast' is also binary but  'hours of sleep' is numeric so you must preprocess for the same scale.

And after you may create two models 1) for  'hours of sleep' and 2) 'having breakfast' and use metric for ample 'gain' to compare results

Comment: thank you. So would I have to do logistic regression for 'hours of sleep' and 'falling asleep at work, and then separate logistic regression for 'having breakfast' and 'falling asleep at work' and then compare the values?

Comment: yes, the simpliest way is to make two separate regession equations.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to interpret "be a better predictor" in this context. One possible way is to fit a model for "falling asleep at work" using "hours of sleep" (model 1), fit another one with the same outcome using "having breakfast" instead (model 2) and to compare whether model 1 or model 2 predicts better the variations of the outcome "falling asleep at work".

As suggested by Edward in his comments, a solution is to fit a logistic regression for each predictor. One interesting output of each regression is a set of predicted values (a vector $\hat y_1$ for model 1 and $\hat y_2$ for model 2). One can then compare the values of the outcome $y$ to $\hat y_1$ and to $\hat y_2$, for instance computing the percentage of observations for which the prediction $\hat y$ is equal to the realised value of the outcome $y$. Hours of sleep will be a better predictor than having breakfast for the outcome falling asleep at work if the measure is higher for model 1 than for model 2.